# how to remove style from text while paste in a editable div

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have a editable div. and I want when user copy a text which contain color or bold text and paste it in my editable div , only plain text should be paste .
 my code is ..

```
 public void onModuleLoad() {
  final HTMLPanel html = new HTMLPanel("<div id='list'> </div>");
  html.addStyleName("dv");
  html.getElement().setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");

  RootPanel.get().add(html);

  handleFileSelect1();

 }
  public static native void handleFileSelect1()
  /*-{      
    /*-{   
function handleFileSelect(evt){ 
    alert("paste");
}


$doc.getElementById('list').addEventListener('paste', handleFileSelect, true);                                                                                          
 }-*/;
```

this is not working.,

Comment: Are you trying to remove html tags or just html tags as plain text ?

Comment: i want only plain text

Comment: its provides my alert on past event but how can i get plain text

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine using [Element#getInnerText()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getInnerText%28%29) with the one exception case for first pasted HTML.

```
HTMLPanel html = new HTMLPanel("<div id='list'> </div>") {
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
            case Event.ONPASTE: {
                // The Logic is here set inner HTML from the inner Text
                getElement().setInnerHTML(getElement().getInnerText());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
html.sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE);

html.addStyleName("dv");
html.getElement().setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
```

**Note :** You can think in this direction. Meanwhile I am also trying to resolve the exception case.

Comment: @mark Please have a look at [clipboardData object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms535220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)